# spring boot jdbc auth with password encoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication

I want to create authentication on my website and I have created SecurityConfiguration class which looks:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}pass").authorities("ADMIN");

        auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource);    
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/pics/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/managament").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/management")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();

    }

}
```

In my `resources/application.properties` I have two queries

```
spring.queries.users-query=select username, password, active from user where username=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.username, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.username=?
```

And also below are my entities

**Role**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int roleId;

    @Setter
    private String role;    

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;

    @Setter
    private String password;

    @Setter
    private String username;

    @Setter
    private int active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @Setter
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User(String password, String username, int active, Set<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

In SQL Database I have one more table which contains user_id and role_id because it's relation many to many.

My repositories extends `JpaRepository`.

Everything is working when I'm using in memory authentication so I suppose that HttpSecurity and WebSecurity are configured properly. The problem is when I use

```
auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource);
```

It throws me `o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`.

Some tells that password field in DB should be larger than 60 chars because of BCryptPasswordEncoder but I have more chars for it and some tell about additional configuration.

I used [this](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d) example and this guy don't have that config that people are talking about. I just cut some not useful parts of code and adjusted it to my needs. But I'm missing something and I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had password in my database like `$2y$12$HCch5QVPslL4UjtZRuCqiuhYybBeBujdyMj.oyH1BTSA6zJFJlZ2C`

because I generated it with [this](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) bcrypt generator. By default bcrypt strength is **10** in **BCryptPasswordEncoder.class**. As you can see there is $2y$**12**$ at the begining and this 12 is strength, so when I was trying to encode my password it didn't look like bcrypt because of the begining **$2y$12$** which should be **$2y$10$** for this configuration

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

If you want to change strength to 12 you should do this

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
}
```